# how can i add a checklist to all cards and boards in trello?

Tags: automation, trello

I would like that when adding a checklist to a card in trello, that checklist would be added to all cards.
Example : [https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiCF9.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyJne.png) it's in the beggining , and the I added a checklist called "teste" https://prnt.sc/i9jGTQ3EePJ_ , I wanna add this checklist "teste" for all these cards.https://prnt.sc/a_w13zh7FaAm

** I don't know nothing about coding , I wanna do all this with butler

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the second screenshot, but if you want to add a checklist to every card, I can think of a way to do it.

First of all, to do this to existing cards, which it sounds like is what you're looking for, probably create a rule for something like "when label `{pick a color}` is added to a card, add the `teste` checklist from card `https://the-link-of-the-card-its-on` to the card".

Then i'd add the Bulk Actions power-up to your board, and use that to select all the cards on your board and add the label to them. After the checklists are added, you can use Bulk Actions again to remove the label.